# How to bulk insert using sequelize and postgres

Tags: sequelize.js

Here I tried to insert bulk data in my sequelize db but it creates problem.
How to bulk insert using sequelize and postgres in angularjs?

Comment: I tried sequelize cli but listing me seed flag is missing

Answer (score 4):

First of all create seed file using `sequelize seed:create --name nameofseed` it will create seeder folder in your root directory, add the `seederStorage:'sequelize'` in `config.js` of `development:{seederStorage:'sequelize'}`
give the table name here is `offer` but in db it is `offers` and table fields in json objects.
after creating seeder it needs to `migrate` and `run` respectively.
here is command to run the seed: `sequelize db:seed:all` before it run the migrate command which is: `sequelize db:migrate` thats it.

```
 module.exports = {
      up: function(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
        queryInterface.bulkInsert('offers', [{
          ban: [1],
          sDate: '2016-03-31T08:00:10.354Z',
          eDate: '2016-03-31T08:00:10.354Z',
          isActive: true,
          reminder: false,
          sold: false,
          couponFor: 'Coupon Code',
          couponVal: 'Flat20%',
          createdAt: '2016-03-31T08:00:10.354Z',
          updatedAt: '2016-03-31T08:00:10.354Z'
        },
        {
          ban: [1, 2],
          sDate: '2016-03-31T08:00:10.354Z',
          eDate: '2016-03-31T08:00:10.354Z',
          isActive: true,
          reminder: false,
          sold: false,
          couponFor: 'Coupon Code',
          couponVal: 'Flat40%',
          createdAt: '2016-03-31T08:00:10.354Z',
          updatedAt: '2016-03-31T08:00:10.354Z'
        },
        {
          ban: [1, 2],
          sDate: '2016-03-31T08:00:10.354Z',
          eDate: '2016-03-31T08:00:10.354Z',
          isActive: true,
          reminder: false,
          sold: false,
          couponFor: 'Coupon Code',
          couponVal: 'Flat60%',
          createdAt: '2016-03-31T08:00:10.354Z',
          updatedAt: '2016-03-31T08:00:10.354Z'
        },
        {
          ban: [1],
          sDate: '2016-03-31T08:00:10.354Z',
          eDate: '2016-03-31T08:00:10.354Z',
          isActive: true,
          reminder: false,
          sold: false,
          couponFor: 'Coupon Code',
          couponVal: 'Flat100%',
          createdAt: '2016-03-31T08:00:10.354Z',
          updatedAt: '2016-03-31T08:00:10.354Z'
        }], {});
        /*
          Add altering commands here.
          Return a promise to correctly handle asynchronicity.

          Example:
          return queryInterface.bulkInsert('Person', [{
            name: 'John Doe',
            isBetaMember: false
          }], {});
        */
      },

      down: function(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
        /*
          Add reverting commands here.
          Return a promise to correctly handle asynchronicity.

          Example:
          return queryInterface.bulkDelete('Person', null, {});
        */
      }
    };
```

Comment: if `development:{seederStorage:'sequelize'}` is not set in config.js either its fine

Comment: can I use bulkInsert() in a migration file?

Comment: Can you please add any example or documentations link of sequelize? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @maxwell yes you can

Answer (score 0):

```
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface
      .createTable('tests', {
        id: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, autoIncrement: false, primaryKey: true },
        name: { type: Sequelize.STRING },
        code: { type: Sequelize.STRING },
        imageUrl: { type: Sequelize.STRING },
        groupId: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, allowNull: true },
        createdAt: { type: Sequelize.DATE, allowNull: true },
        updatedAt: { type: Sequelize.DATE, allowNull: true },
      })
      .then(() => {
        queryInterface.bulkInsert('tests', [
          {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Test One',
            code: 'TC',
            imageUrl: 'https://google.com',
            groupId: null,
            createdAt: new Date(),
            updatedAt: new Date(),
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Test One',
            code: 'SCC',
            imageUrl: 'https://google.com',
            groupId: null,
            createdAt: new Date(),
            updatedAt: new Date(),
          },
          {
            id: 3,
            name: 'Test One',
            code: 'CM',
            imageUrl: 'https://google.com',
            groupId: null,
            createdAt: new Date(),
            updatedAt: new Date(),
          },
          {
            id: 4,
            name: 'Test One',
            code: 'UM',
            imageUrl: 'https://google.com',
            groupId: null,
            createdAt: new Date(),
            updatedAt: new Date(),
          },
          {
            id: 5,
            name: 'Test One',
            code: 'DDM',
            imageUrl: 'https://google.com',
            groupId: null,
            createdAt: new Date(),
            updatedAt: new Date(),
          },
          {
            id: 6,
            name: 'Test One',
            code: '',
            imageUrl: 'https://google.com',
            groupId: 3,
            createdAt: new Date(),
            updatedAt: new Date(),
          },
          {
            id: 7,
            name: 'Test One',
            code: '',
            imageUrl: 'https://google.com',
            groupId: 4,
            createdAt: new Date(),
            updatedAt: new Date(),
          },
        ]);
      });
  },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('tests');
  },
};
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This how you can bulkInsert () using migrations
for more reference see this repository
https://github.com/hussainghazali/Migrations-with-value-nodeJS

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).